# Zend Framework Validate field is integer between 1 and 5

Tags: validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter class for form validation. **point** field should accept only integers between 1 and 5. But it doesn't work properly it accepts  string starting with integers between 1 and 5. For example 1kjhkjh, 2tgfjhgfjhf, 4jhkljg...
What is wrong in my code?

```
$inputFilter->add (
            $inputFilter->getFactory()->createInput (
                array (
                    'name' => 'point',
                    'required' => true,
                    'validators' => array ( 
                        array(
                            'name' => 'Digits'),    
                        array (
                            'name' => 'Between',
                            'options' => array (
                                'min' => 1,
                                'max' => 5,
                                'messages' => array('notBetween' => 'Point must be between %min% and %max%')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: A workaround would be to add a string length of 1.

Answer (score 3):

Use the the second parameter of zend validator to break the validators chain and return an error, `breakChainOnFailure` ([documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.validator_chains.html)) tells the element to stop validating if this error is triggered, so in your case if it is not a digit the user gets an error, when the user has fixed the error the second validator will get triggered too:

```
$inputFilter->add (
            $inputFilter->getFactory()->createInput (
                array (
                    'name' => 'point',
                    'required' => true,
                    'validators' => array ( 
                        array(
                            'name' => 'Digits', 'breakChainOnFailure' => true),    
                        array (
                            'name' => 'Between',
                            'options' => array (
                                'min' => 1,
                                'max' => 5,
                                'messages' => array('notBetween' => 'Point must be between %min% and %max%')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Another option would be to replace `Zend_Validate_Digits` with `Zend_Validate_Int` ([docmentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.int)) depending of what error message you prefer to give to the user if he enters non valid data. Of course as suggested in the comments you could also use the `Zend_Filter_Int` if what you want is to handle any non valid data by fixing it yourself and do not give the user feedback about what he did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
'breakChainOnFailure': true
```

should be

```
'breakChainOnFailure'=> true
```